# ID3 implementation using gain ratio

Tags: java, decision-tree, id3

I have implemented ID3 (using information gain to choose the best attribute), and it works fine. However, now I am experimenting with other heuristics, such as gain ratio. The gain ratio is calculated correctly, but when I use the value of the gain ratio to split the tree it really comes weird and complex.
Do you have to do something to the gain ratio value, or just use it as you use the information gain (i.e choose the attribute with the biggest gain ratio)?

Comment: [Relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13302778/645270)

Comment: thanks but did not exactly answer my problem :(

Answer (score 0):

First, note that `GR = IG/IV` (where `GR` is [gain ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_gain_ratio), `IG` is information gain, and `IV` is information value (aka intrinsic value)), so in case `IV = 0`, `GR` is undefined. An example for such a case is when the attribute's value is the same for all of the training examples.

Now, Quinlan defined `GR` in [Induction of decision trees](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00116251) in order to counter the bias of `IG` toward attributes with many values. However, he also pointed out that `GR` might be biased toward attributes whose `IV` is very small.
To counter this bias, Quinlan noted that while choosing the attribute with highest gain ratio, one should only consider attributes whose `IG` is average-or-better.

If I understand correctly, considering only attributes with average-or-better `IG` helps to counter the bias toward attributes with a very small `IV`, because `IG <= IV`. (For more on that, see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/360901/215801).)

Maybe this would improve your results.